# How to remove inactive icon from installing software?

Tags: unity, software-center, icons

A very simple question, but for which for some reasons I do not seem to be able to find a solution yet: I have re-install a 3rd party software (notifyOSD) from the new software center (Ive got Ubuntu 16) but the icon get stuck in the menu without installing anything. Meanwhile I have already reinstall the software from a terminal, but the icon just seems to stuck there, even when I reboot. Anyone knows a command to kill the process?

Many thanks in advance,

Jean

Comment: Removing the launcher was not doing it, but rebooting for second time did. Problem solved! Btw, sorry if I have been unclear in my formuling...

Answer (score 0):

Removing the launcher was not doing it, but rebooting for second time did. Problem solved! Btw, sorry if I have been unclear in my formuling